# What was Billy's goal for becoming a cop and going undercover?

Tags: character, the-departed

In *The Departed*, Billy Costigan he was very intelligent and could have been anything he wanted to be, but he chose to become a state trooper. Why? What was his goal for becoming a cop and going undercover?

Comment: Maybe this is what he wanted to be more than anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emanuel Levy has some [relevant quotes from Leonardo DiCaprio](http://emanuellevy.com/comment/the-departed-dicaprio-6/):

> Billy Costigan came up from the streets of Boston, and DiCaprio
> remarks that **his character's motivation to become a police officer is
> rooted in his desire to escape his upbringing**: “Billy comes from an
> underworld background and has all the chips stacked against him in a
> lot of ways. **I think he joins the police because he has no other
> options, and he wants to do things differently than his family did.**”
>
> “Ironically, he is asked to go undercover and pretend to be the very
> thing he was determined not to become. At the heart of it, I think
> Billy is ultimately trying to redeem himself and not just be a product
> of his environment, but he ends up deep in a situation that is
> extremely dangerous and deceitful. There are moments when he could so
> easily be caught. All the arrows are pointing in his direction as the
> 'rat,' and everything begins to cave in around him.”

The same quote is also in ["The art of writing and making films: THE DEPARTED"](https://web.archive.org/web/20071108084033/https://writingstudio.co.za/page1383.html). (link to archived page in the Wayback Machine, since the original apparently hasn't been available for several years)

Comment: Second link is dead.

Comment: @DennisHackethal Fixed.